# @bot.command() и @bot.event() клонируются. discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

````
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from asyncio import sleep
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!') #инициализируем бота с префиксом(то есть бот отвечает на сообщения, начинающиеся с префикса '!')
hello_words = ['hello', 'hi', 'privet', 'qq', 'ky', 'ку', 'q', 'helo','привет']
goodbye_word = ['бб', 'bb', 'goodbye', 'пока', 'poka', 'прощай', 'до завтра', 'bb all', 'бб олл', 'бб алл',]
pep = ["Ая, как дела?","Ая, как дела","ая, как дела?","ая, как дела","Ая, как ты себя чувствуешь?","ая, как ты себя чувствуешь?","Ая, как ты себя чувствуешь","ая, как ты себя чувствуешь","pep"]

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Я готова:З")

@bot.command()
async def шанс(ctx):
    if ctx.author != bot.user:
        choice = random.randint(0, 100)
        await ctx.send(f"шанс равен {choice} %")

@bot.command()
async def орел_решка(ctx):
    await ctx.send(random.choice(['орел', 'решка']))
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound ):
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'** {ctx.author.name}, данной команды не существует.**', color=0x0c0c0c))

@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):  
    msg = message.content.lower()  

    if msg in hello_words:  
        await message.channel.send(f'Привет, чем могу помочь?')
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()

    if msg in goodbye_word:
        await message.channel.send(f'Что?, ты уже уходишь? Ладно, пока-пока!')
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()

    if msg in pep:
        await message.channel.send(f"Я еще не чувствую боли... Мой создатель явно халтурщик..")
    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run(token)```
Сообщения от бота клонируются, причем и ивенты, и команды
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

А в чём проблема оптимизировать код и делать все проверки в одном ивенте `on_message()`

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):  
    msg = message.content.lower()  

    if msg in hello_words:  
        await message.channel.send(f'Привет, чем могу помочь?')
    elif msg in goodbye_word:
        await message.channel.send(f'Что?, ты уже уходишь? Ладно, пока-пока!')
    elif msg in pep:
        await message.channel.send(f"Я еще не чувствую боли... Мой создатель явно халтурщик..")

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Сделал, всё та же проблема

Comment: какая проблема, код ошибки отправьте

Comment: ошибки как таковой нет. Просто бот несколько раз отправляет одно и тоже сообщение без надобности

Comment: А, это из-за того, что у вас в списке много вариантов сообщений, после ```await message.channel.send()``` используйте оператор ```break```

Comment: тогда нужно заменить if на while. Но всё равно спасибо.